# Is it possible to send async requests to 100,000 websites in 1 second?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have very powerful cpu, ram and 1Gbit/s of internet. But the code below uses only 1% of my resources.

I am trying the below code but the requests are not asynchronous. At first 1000 requests happen quickly, but after that it starts to slow down.

```
import requests
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import time

list_of_urls = []
with open("urllist.txt","r") as readurl:
    for i in readurl.readlines():
        list_of_urls.append("http://"+i.replace("\n","").strip())



def get_url(url):
    try:
        req =requests.get(url,timeout=4)
        req.close()
        return req
    except:
        return "TIMEOUT ERR"


start_time = time.time()
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=int(len(list_of_urls) / 2)) as pool:
    list(pool.map(get_url, list_of_urls))

print((start_time - time.time()) * -1)
```

Is it possible to send async requests to 100,000 websites in 1 second?

Comment: Depends entirely on the speed of your internet and ISP specific filters designed to prevent this type of thing

Comment: Most ISPs will reserve high speed for short bursts while long running or uploads downloads get less speed. Async has nothing to do with it.

Comment: If all your URLs are on the same site, the site itself could be throttling you, too. Respectful web scraping should not be done too fast, and if you try to go too fast, you risk getting blocked altogether by some sites.